# Advantage(s) of cube/tabular model over relational star schemas

Tags: ssas, mdx, data-warehouse, dax

I am wondering whether cubes or tabular models have any advantages over star schemas other than MDX/DAX query speed. Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Christian

Comment: Ok found this: http://larryrockoff.com/2010/04/28/star-schemas-arent-just-for-olap-cubes/ any more comments still very much welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "advantages over star schemas", I am assuming that you mean a Star schema in a relational database?  The primary difference is the potentially orders of magnatitude difference in speed, but in the area of self-service BI, a bigger advantage of Cubes or Models is that they implement an entirely new semantic layer.  They give you the opportunity to rename fields that may have obscure names in the DB, to have more useful recognisable names for the business users and hide more technical fields, that are not useful to end users. You can define reuseable Named Sets and Hierarchies that enable easier, more effective and consistent reporting.
But the two biggies for me are the speed and the business user friendly semantic layer. JK.

Comment: Thanks, yes I meant relational db star schemas.